# lookup value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dax

I have 2 table.

Table 1

```
ID Name
1  AAA
2  BBB
3  CCC
```

Table 2

```
ID Name
1  AAC
2  BBB
4  DDD
```

As output, I would like to to find out -

when the ID matches between 2 tables do we have the same Name there, if so the Output should be Name Match or Name mismatch. Else if the ID is not found between those 2 tables, the output should be "ID Not found"

Expected result -

```
ID Name Result
1  AAA  Name mismatch
2  BBB  Name match
3  CCC  ID Not found
```

Anyone knows which query I should use in Excel to get the expected result!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,E:E,0)),IF(COUNTIFS(E:E,A2,F:F,B2),"Name Match","Name Mismatch"),"ID Not Found")
```

[image]

---

Or this shorter formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A2,E:F,2,FALSE)=B2,"Name Match","Name Mismatch"),"ID Not Found")
```